# how to make top level menu item not active?

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1, submenu

I have created 2 drop down categories in the menu bar each having some sub menus

Is it possible somehow to set it in a way that a visitor can click it but it won't do anything other than show the dropdown so users must select one of the subcategories to see the products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty js solution:

```
$$('.level0 > a').each(function(elem){
    $(elem).href="#";
})
```

Include this code in your footer.